# How to convert Unix epoch to a timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I am new to postgresql bot not to sql in general. I have a table that I need to read values from, on of the columns is a unix timestamp that I want to convert in to a more human readable format thus I found this:

```
SELECT lt,dw,up,to_char(uxts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
from products;
```

But that produces an error:
ERROR:  multiple decimal points

I am lost here. I am sure someone can show me how to do it. The documentation isn't that clear to me. Postgresql 9.5 is the database.

Comment: A column that stores a number is not a "timestamp" - it's a number. A timestamp column is one that is defined as `timestamp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`to_char()` converts a number, date or timestamp to a string, not the other way round.

You want [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

> Convert Unix epoch (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00) to timestamp

---

So just apply that function on your column

```
SELECT lt,dw,up,to_timestamp(uxts) as uxts 
from products;
```

This assumes that uxts is some kind of number data type (`integer`, `bigint` or `double precision`)